# Keeping <li>filters active and inactive in React.JS

Tags: reactjs, toggle

So here's the deal: I am creating search filters in React and want them to be toggleable. Seperate of each other. Im not sure which method I should use and how to do it. Any tips guys? Here's how far i have come :

In my render method I have:

```
  let filterSelectClass = (this.state.selectFilter
  ? "selected"
  : "unselected")
```

in my return I have:

```
<li className={filterSelectClass} id="1" onClick={this.toggleFilter.bind(this, 1)} >1900 - 1925</li>
<li className={filterSelectClass} id="2" onClick={this.toggleFilter.bind(this, 2)} >1925 - 1950</li>
```

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps...

I would recommend you to use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) to manipulate the classes in react. I'll reduce the complexity.

**Toggle multiple `<li>` element(Like AND)**

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      toggle: {
        one: false,
        two: false,
      }
    }
  }
  
  toggleFilter(e){
    const newObj = {
        [e.target.id]: !this.state.toggle[e.target.id]
      }
    this.setState({
      toggle: Object.assign({}, this.state.toggle, newObj)
    })
  }
  
  render(){
    return <div>
      <li className={this.state.toggle.one ? 'selected' : 'unselected'} id="one" onClick={this.toggleFilter.bind(this)} >1900 - 1925</li>
      <li className={this.state.toggle.two ? 'selected' : 'unselected'} id="two" onClick={this.toggleFilter.bind(this)} >1925 - 1950</li>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.selected {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Toggle single `<li>` element (Like OR)**

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      toggle: {
        one: false,
        two: false,
      }
    }
  }
  
  toggleFilter(e){
    this.setState({
      toggle: {
        [e.target.id]: !this.state.toggle[e.target.id]
      }
    })
  }
  
  render(){
    return <div>
      <li className={this.state.toggle.one ? 'selected' : 'unselected'} id="one" onClick={this.toggleFilter.bind(this)} >1900 - 1925</li>
      <li className={this.state.toggle.two ? 'selected' : 'unselected'} id="two" onClick={this.toggleFilter.bind(this)} >1925 - 1950</li>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.selected{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```